# How can I calculate the torque of a helicopter's main rotor?

Tags: helicopter

Might be a simple answer that I am overlooking but...

I am attempting to determine the torque of a helicopter main rotor so that I can design an anti-torque rotor to counteract it. Anyone aware of of a simplified formula for this? I have been unable to find such a thing.

Comment: Some more info [here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/67197/21091)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Power is torque times angular velocity. Hence, torque = power/angular velocity

For example, for a power of 200 hp and angular velocity 400 RPMs, using SI units –> 200 hp = 149000 W    400 RPMs = 41.9 rad/s

Torque = 149000/41.9 = 3556 newton-meter.